# Using Project Reactor with Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, project-reactor

I'd like to know if it is possible to use Project Reactor with Apache Camel, so applications be fully reactive and non-blocking IO. I'd like to know how does the Project Reactor support works when integrating other Apache Camel's components.

Can I read for example from S3 reactively (therefore I'll need to use the Async S3 client behind the scenes)? Or will I block when reading from S3 and then just create a Flux out of what has been returned?

Comment: Are you referring to using the `aws2-s3` component or are you referring to writing your own endpoint and route processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where reactiveness is needed, you should use the relevant spring and reactor libraries. there are pseudo camel code also u can db call in camel bean or processors etc

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/books")
@RequiredArgsContructor
public class HomeController {

    private final BookRepository bookRepository;
    private final ProducerTemplate template

    @GetMapping("")
    public Flux<Book> getHome() {

        List <Book>  books=bookRepository.findAll();
        X ret = template.requestBody("direct:something", books, X.class);


    }


}

@Component
public class SomeRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

     from("direct:something")
                .process(e-> {

                   List<Book> books = e.getIn.getBody(List.class)

                    // some logic 

                   e.getIn.setBody(new X( ))

                })
}
```